# EditText takes only last value in dynamic form

Tags: android, datepicker, retrofit2, dynamicform

I have created a dynamic form. The field in the form is created in respect to the field type set in the backend. All the data of the dynamically created editText is set in arrayList. There is no problem for type "String" but in case of date, a problem occurs. The problem is that if there are 2 date fields, the value of the last datefield is set even if i chose and set the date field of first date field. The code can be seen below:

```
 call.enqueue(new Callback<SifarisMainModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SifarisMainModel> call, retrofit2.Response<SifarisMainModel> response) {
            String url = call.request().toString();
            Log.e("urlChoseSifaris",url.toString() + "");

            for(FieldArray fieldArray: response.body().getFiledArray()){
                counter++;
                name = fieldArray.getNepaliName();
                fieldType = fieldArray.getFieldType();
                keyList.add(fieldArray.getName());
                getForm();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SifarisMainModel> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    }); 



 public  void getForm(){
 case "DATE":
            et = new EditText(this);
            list.add(et);
            et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME);
            et.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
            sifarisMainlayout.addView(et);
            et.setFocusable(false);
            et.setCursorVisible(false);
et.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(ChooseSifaris.this,
                            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker view, int year,
                                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                   et.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                                }
                            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                    datePickerDialog.show();
                }
            });
 break;

}
```

Comment: it could be because the clicklistner for date picker is set on the last date form, it's not clear from this code snippet though.

Comment: @NIKHILMAURYA yes it is taking only last date form.

Comment: move list.add(et) after the assignment of clicklistner

Comment: @NIKHILMAURYA it is still not working bro. same prob. the value of last form with date changes

Comment: Add one more line EditText et = new EditText(this); instead of et = new EditText(this); I don't think this would work either but let's try it.